# How to skip a stage in Jenkinsfile pipeline when pipeline name ends with deliver?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have 2 pipelines one for review and one for deploy. So when the pipeline ends with review, I want to skip Jenkinsfile execution. However, when it ends with deploy, it should execute the stage or the Jenkinsfile.

I tried to use `if`, but this is a declarative pipeline, so when should be used. I want to avoid execution of stage using when condition if I encounter deploy pipeline end.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
final boolean Deploy = (env.JOB_NAME as String).endsWith("-deploy")

    
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(
            choices: ['greeting' , 'silence'],
            description: '',
            name: 'REQUESTED_ACTION')
    }

    stages {
//how to ouse when here to use deploy vairable to avoide execution of stage below
        stage ('Speak') {
            
            steps {
                echo "Hello, bitwiseman!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can skip stages in declarative pipelines using [`when`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when), so the following should work.

```java
stages {
  stage('Deploy') {
    when { equals expected: true, actual: Deploy }
    steps {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @stephenking i am not expecting this solution this will compulsory eliminate stage my question is very simple    I have 2 piepline supose 1 and 2 pipeline 1 is ending with review  and pipeline i.e job 2 ending with deploy now i have same jenkinsfile with only one stage i want to skip that stage execution only when i run first pipeline ending with review but i want to execute it when pipeline end with deliver so need this tricky solutio

Comment: If it should be totally invisible in the review pipeline, then use scripted pipelines and wrap the stage with an `if` statement.

Comment: no i am using delivery pipeline dont want to mix together

Comment: @DeepakRaut, As per your description of the question, this must be the accepted solution. Contrary to what you believe, this does not compulsorily eliminate the stage. Rather, the stage is skipped only when the variable `Deploy` evaluates to Boolean `false`.

Answer (score 16):

An alternative to @StephenKing’s answer, which is also correct, you can rewrite the `when` block when evaluating Booleans as follows:

```
stages {
    stage('Deploy') {
        when { 
            expression {
                return Deploy
            }
        }
        steps {
            echo "Hello, bitwiseman!" // Step executes only when Deploy is true

        }
    }
}
```

This will execute the stage Deploy only when the variable `Deploy` evaluates to true, else the stage will be skipped.

Answer (score 14):

I've got quite a hard time to find it too, but finally:

```
stage('Speak') {
     when {
         expression { params.REQUESTED_ACTION != 'SILENCE' }
     }
     steps {
         echo "Hello, bitwiseman!"
     }
}
```

Jenkins docs with examples here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when-example

Answer (score 0):

Even you can skip some parts of the steps using below code. Let's say `REQUIRED_UPLOAD_INSTALL` is a parameter.

```
stage('Checking Mail List') {
  steps {
    script {
      if(!(env.REQUIRED_UPLOAD_INSTALL.toBoolean())) {
        env.mail_list = 'test@testg.com'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't support in post steps, not even in the when syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a Jenkins scripted pipeline:

```
stage('Input of Scratch instance and Access token') {
    timeout(time: 60, unit: 'SECONDS') {
        script {
            try {
                env.SCRATCH_INSTANCE_URL = input message: 'Please enter the SCRATCH_INSTANCE_URL',
                                                parameters: [string(defaultValue: '',
                                                         description: '',
                                                         name: 'SCRATCH_INSTANCE_URL')]
                env.SCRATCH_ACCESS_TOKEN = input message: 'Please enter the SCRATCH_ACCESS_TOKEN',
                                                parameters: [string(defaultValue: '',
                                                             description: '',
                                                             name: 'SCRATCH_ACCESS_TOKEN')]
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                echo "Caught ${e.toString()}"
                            currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
            }
        }
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Logout from Dev Hub.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
            
stage('Logout from DevHub') {
    if (env.SCRATCH_INSTANCE_URL == null) {
        rc = command '''export SFDX_USE_GENERIC_UNIX_KEYCHAIN=true
             sfdx force:auth:logout --targetusername ${DEV_HUB_USERNAME} -p
             echo ${SCRATCH_INSTANCE_URL}
             echo ${SCRATCH_ACCESS_TOKEN}
             '''
    } else {
        echo "Skipping this stage"
    }
}
```