# Jenkins Pipeline with Matrix Axes - Pick Axes before running job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

Using Jenkins Pipeline script and the `matrix` syntax, I can add multiple values for one axis, so multiple jobs run and can use that value to pull in an ENV file for example.

However, there might be times when I only want to run the job for one or two of the axis values.

I think I need to use the `extendedChoice` parameter, which will provide a list of checkboxes, but I can't find anything online about how to plug that into the `matrix` part of my pipeline script.

Here is an example of what I have so far

```
    agent none
    parameters {
        extendedChoice multiSelectDelimiter: ',', name: 'CLIENT', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', value: 'client1,client2,client3', visibleItemCount: 20
        gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)', defaultValue: 'develop', name: 'BRANCH', type: 'PT_BRANCH'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            matrix {
                agent any
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'CLIENT'
                        values 'client1', 'client2', 'client3'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Running job') {
                        steps {
                            echo "Job running for ${CLIENT}"
                        }
                    }
                    stage('Checkout') {
                        steps {
                            git branch: "${params.BRANCH}", url: 'git@github.com:my-username/jenkins-pipeline-test.git', credentialsId: 'Jenkins EC2'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this script lets me pick a branch from my repo, but currently the checkbox list provided by `extendedChoice` doesn't do anything, and the job runs 3 times for each "client"

Answer (score 0):

Use variable for axe values is a feature request, not implemented yet:

- https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-62127
- https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-61047

So it is not possible to use a variable to set the axe values.

### Options

1. Fork the [official plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/matrix-project-plugin) and add the feature. I learned a lot of jenkins doing this
2. Use this plugin [Jenkins Dynamic Axis Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/dynamic-axis/)
3. On each stage validate if client was selected in the choice parameter and skip the execution if don't match

### Option #3 : Skip the stage execution

Using [when step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57910679/3957754) you could skip the stage execution

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        extendedChoice 
            multiSelectDelimiter: ',', 
            name: 'SELECTED_CLIENT', quoteValue: false, 
            saveJSONParameterToFile: false, 
            type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', 
            value: 'client1,client2,client3', 
            visibleItemCount: 20
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            matrix {
                agent any
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'CLIENT'
                        values 'client1', 'client2', 'client3'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage('Running job') {
                    when {
                      expression { params.SELECTED_CLIENT != CLIENT }
                        }                        
                    steps {
                        echo "Job running for ${CLIENT}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you choose client2, you will see that only client1 and client2 are executed

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work correctly for me. If I select client1 and client 2, all 3 client jobs run

Comment: Could you share your configuration? I will re validate it today ;)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/paul-uz/9e4ecdc03faf4d36bf50fc85d75514a7

Comment: My results are very odd. Picking client2, client1 and client3 "build", but when i pick client1 and client3, all of them "build"